# vi losing lines when pasting/inserting via screen

Tags: vi, gnu-screen

Any suggestions for what's wrong with vi? If I go into `i`nsert mode then paste text using `Ctrl+V`, OR alternatively use `o` or `O` to insert lines, it often seems like the display has got out of sync with the file - sometimes multiple lines will disappear but doing a `wq` and reopening shows the intended change has occured.

This is when running in gnu screen.

Comment: What happens if, instead of quitting, you press `CTRL-l` (lowecase L) ?

Comment: I get something like`^L^L^Lfirst line of my file` pasted at a random(?) horizontal position